# Не работает PopUp окно в чем проблема?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть PopUp окно

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.call_popup').click(function(){
        $('.popup').toggleClass('open');
    });
    $('.popup_header i').click(function(){
        $('.popup').removeClass('open');
    })
});
```

Есть подключенные к нему стили

```
.popup {
    display:none;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 200px 0 rgba(32,19,45,0.90);
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50%-125px);
    left: calc(50%-125px);
 }
 .popup.open {
     display: block;
 }
 .popup_header {
     position: relative;
 }
 .popup_header i {
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     right: 5px;
 }
```

Не могу понять почему не работает ?

Comment: добавьте в клик-обработчики `console.log("click");`. Что-нибудь появляется в консоли?

Answer (score 2):

Ты не добавил HTML код, по этому я набросал свою модалку. Надеюсь идея понятна.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.call_popup').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').fadeToggle('open');
    });
});
```

```css
.popup{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  display: none;
}

.popup_box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed coral;
}

.close{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="call_popup">OpenPopup</button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup_box">
    <a href="#" class="call_popup close">+</a>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <button type="submit">Lorem</button>
  </div>
</div>
```